# Changing KML data in a Fusion table at different zoom levels

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I'm using a Google Fusion Table that has data for all countries (and many states / provinces as well). My project currently only uses US, Canada, and Mexico, but the data set I'm using appears to have all countries.

My problem is that at certain zoom levels a US state (New Mexico) and two regions in Mexico (Baja California and Baja California Sur) disappear. If you zoom in further, part of NM reappears but not the whole state. I'm wondering where in the world to start digging into a resolution for this.

Here's the fusion table I'm using:

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=420419#map

If you look at the map tab (might have to create it) and zoom in / out you'll see how NM and Baja California (sometimes 1 of them, sometimes both) appear and disappear. If you zoom in further, a square within NM appears but it's not at all the shape of the state.

Initial Zoom Level

[image: Initial zoom level]

Zoomed out it looks fine.

[image: Zoomed out it looks fine:]

Zoomed in close it looks really strange

[image: Zoomed in close it looks really strange]

Any thoughts on how to dig into the data of this fusion table or find one that has better, yet equivalent, data? We need state/province data as well so we can click on states and process the response in JavaScript.

I wonder if the root issue is different levels of detail at different zoom levels - just not sure how to discover who to even contact if that's the case.